# System.InvalidOperationException : 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

My application is basically with .net Core 3.1 (Code-First Approach).

While migrating my application from .net 5 to 6.

We are using Entity Framework Core and have encountered the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by the navigation property 'FrontPage.PartyANavigation' of type 'Company'.
Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'

This is how the relationship is managed between the company entity and the frontpage entity.

```
public partial class Company : BaseEntity
    {     
       
        // other properties
        public virtual ICollection<FrontPage> FrontPagePartyANavigation { get; } = new HashSet<FrontPage>();
        public virtual ICollection<FrontPage> FrontPagePartyBNavigation { get; } = new HashSet<FrontPage>();
        public virtual ICollection<FrontPage> FrontPageToSolicitorNavigation { get; } = new HashSet<FrontPage>();
      
    } 


public partial class FrontPage : BaseEntity
    {
        // other properties
        public virtual Company? PartyANavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Company? PartyBNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Company? ToSolicitorNavigation { get; set; }
       
    }
}
```

This exception occurs at the baseRepository while setting the database.

I understand that the exception message suggests manually configuring the relationship, but I'm not sure how to do that.
Can someone guide me on how to resolve this issue and properly configure the relationship using Entity Framework Core?

We are willing to migrate our application from .NET 5 to .NET 6. I'm facing the above-mentioned exception.

I tried the [Not Mapped] attribute, but still the exception persists.

I need guidance to solve this exception in order to complete the migration successfully.

Comment: I think you need to configure the relationship between the `Company` and `FrontPage` entities explicitly in the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use FluentAPI to configure the relationships. Small example below but you have to configure the Foreign Keys too (not provided in your example)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

modelBuilder.Entity<FrontPage>()
    .HasOne(fp => fp.PartyANavigation)
    .WithMany(c => c.FrontPagePartyANavigation);

modelBuilder.Entity<FrontPage>()
    .HasOne(fp => fp.PartyBNavigation)
    .WithMany(c => c.FrontPagePartyBNavigation);

modelBuilder.Entity<FrontPage>()
    .HasOne(fp => fp.ToSolicitorNavigation)
    .WithMany(c => c.FrontPageToSolicitorNavigation); 

base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```